# bounding box height working in chrome not working in Jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, jsfiddle

I just made a game like whack a mole to in which the blocks gets highlighted at the specified time 
and the user keeps on clicking on the blocks.Once 10 successful clicks are made, the game ends.
The problem is that the game works in chrome but not in jsfiddle.

The main problem is with the code below

```
var addCss = function(oneDivSize,element,rowIndex,colIndex){
    element.style.width = oneDivSize+'%';
    element.style.height = oneDivSize+'%';
    element.style.borderWidth ="1px";
    element.style.borderColor ="green";
    element.style.borderStyle ="solid";
    var boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    element.style.position ="absolute";
    element.style.left =colIndex * boundingRect.width+"px";
    element.style.top =rowIndex * boundingRect.height+"px";       
};
```

boundingRect.height Returns 2 px

But the same code works properly in chrome.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,

Alex

Comment: _“Works in Chrome, but not in jsfiddle”_ – that is comparing apples and oranges, because Chrome is a _browser_ and jsfiddle is just a _platform_ to provide HTML/JS examples …

Comment: @CBroe thanks..but i had found the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue
by replacing getBoundingBox with window.innerHeight.

Regards
Alex